# Help me identify the source of this Fridge knocking/popping sound?

Tags: refrigerator

Not my fridge, but the exact sound: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bzg7WsMHBpg
I live in a studio and sleep right next to my fridge, and this particular noise out of all the ones it makes wakes me up several times a night, so I'm desperate. Sadly, Frigidaire has actually disabled all its customer service due to Covid, even online chat or emailed questions.

I have a Frigidaire FFTR1814TW0

Noise occurs for 10-15 seconds roughly every hour or so

Noise comes from the back of the freezer (it's a top freezer fridge)

Occurs shortly after start of 'cycle' (goes from completely quiet -> the fan and compressor turn on and start working -> this sound within a few seconds -> regular fan/compressor noises until shutdown

Noise is a sort of random burst of knocking noises, not consistently timed in between each knock though, like you'd expect a fan obstruction to be

I've air-dusted the compressor coils on the bottom back. I also took the inner wall of the freezer back off and checked for frost in the fan or the metal ducts back there, didn't seem bad though.

I read somewhere that this sound is the coolant boiling off as it enters the evaporating coils... but that doesn't jive with the timing of the noise - wouldn't it be happening for the entire cooling cycle if that were the case?

Comment: turn off the ice maker and see if that particular sound stops.  Many times the knocking noise is the ice cubes falling into the bin as the screw rotates in the ice maker.

Comment: is the ice bin full of cubes?

Comment: @Programmer66 The icemaker in this fridge isn't set up. There's no water line going in and nothing in the freezer.

Comment: Interesting update: I removed the back wall from inside the freezer - it has the freezer fan  attached, and behind it is a bunch of small thin metal sheets with tubes running through it - I assume the evaporator. Anyway, unscrewing and detaching the back wall but otherwise leaving it sort of hanging in the back of the fridge... and the sound stopped. After 24 hours it feels more frosty and humid in the freezer, but the sound hasn't happened since. I wonder if its the warming/cooling of the metal causing it?

Comment: The fan attached to the panel may be a little loose.  Just enough to rattle the fan or fan is causing the back panel to pop or rattle.  Tighten all the mounting screw and replace the panel and see if it makes a difference